# IIS7 - Blocking IP addresses not working

Tags: iis-7, ip-address

I have added an IP address in IIS7 in the IP address and domain restrictions. From what I have read this should block all traffic to the folder apart from the allowed IP address. For some reason this does not work. If I access the section from my work computer all ok, when I access it from my phone I can still see the page.

Does anyone have any idea why IIS is not blocking all the other IPs out?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You have to put it to default block instead of default allow, and then put in an allow rule. Just having the allow rule is not enough. Click edit feature settings in the IP adress and domain restrictions, change the field "Access for unspecified clients" to Deny and you should be gold.

Comment: years later this stll helps!